MySQL specify primary key sorting order in secondary index
In MySQL 5.7.25 and MariaDB 10.6.15, using InnoDB by default to create below table
create table t1(
id serial,
employee_id int not null,
name varchar(20),
status tinyint,
created_at datetime(3) not null,
updated_at datetime(3) not null,
event CHAR not null,
primary key (id)
);

I know the pk is auto included in secondary index.
For this table, let's say I want to create a secondary index on employee_id but for same employee_id order by id desc.
CREATE INDEX idx_employee_id_id_desc ON t1 (employee_id, id DESC);
Seems the order on id does not work, the show index command indicates idx_employee_id_id_desc.id is still A.
Does any one knows is this allowed in MySQL or MariaDB?
Thanks!

Please publish versions and storage engine

MariaDB has supported DESC indexes since 10.8.1, so any later version has it (ref issue MDEV-13756)

the show index command indicates idx_employee_id_id_desc.id is still A. SHOW INDEX does not show ASC/DESC. See SHOW CREATE TABLE. https://dbfiddle.uk/Z4CvA6lO https://dbfiddle.uk/TfW6hBXI PS. Two indices by (id) are excess.

Added version. Thanks for the info on MariaDB version to support this. thanks!

I tried, seems this works on MySQL 8+, but not 5.7.
Not work on MariaDB 10.6.15 as well.
In MySQL 8.0.37, when create index CREATE INDEX idx_employee_id_id_desc ON t1 (employee_id, id desc);
Then show index from t1 will show
t1  1   idx_employee_id_id_desc 1   employee_id  A
t1  1   idx_employee_id_id_desc 2   id           D


CREATE INDEX idx_employee_id_id_desc ON t1 (employee_id, id desc)

In old versions of MySQL/MariaDB, the DESC is ignored for the index.
In both old and new versions of MySQL/MariaDB, the following is honored whether or not DESC shows up in the INDEX:
ORDER BY id DESC

Phrasing it another way, you must use ORDER BY to get the output in a particular order.  The "desc" declaration in the index may (or may not) have any impact, but only on performance.
